# Need help converting netlogo code from version 3 to 6

Tags: netlogo

I need to convert a code from version 3 of to netlogo to version 6. Until now everything was going just fine, but i got stucked in a line of code that I couldn't convert. Can somebody help me with it?

The code is the following:

```
let list-temp1 values-from aircrafts with [Team != Team-of myself and distance-nowrap myself <= radius][self]
```

where aircrafts is a breed and Team is a variable of aircraft

The problem is that `values-from` has been deprecated. I tryied what the transition guide suggests on section "new 'of' syntax", and thas the result:

```
let list-temp1 of aircrafts with [Team != [Team] of myself and distance-nowrap myself <= radius][self]
```

But I got an error message that says: OF expected this input to be a reporter block, but got anything instead.

Hope I have provided enough information, if not please let me know.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion or code review board. It's strictly you asking a question about a specific problem and you are given a specific answer to that one question.

Comment: I know that, thats why I am asking a question about a specific problem...

Comment: No, you aren't giving a specific problem, you are asking for a bit of code to be translated.   Can you explain what about it needs translating e.g. is something deprecated, and exactly what you have tried and what you are having a problem with?

Comment: This is a perfectly clear question for NetLogo. I have edited to specify the error and nominated for reopen so that I can answer it.

Comment: Yeah, voting to reopen too. It might not appear as such to someone unfamiliar with NetLogo, but this is a pretty straightforward question that has a very specific answer.

Comment: I edited the question to provide more information, hope it's enough, if not, let me know

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help to split this up into parts. The original code is:

```
let list-temp1 values-from aircrafts with [Team != Team-of myself and distance-nowrap myself <= radius][self]
```

This is rather hard to follow. I think it's easier if we split it up into two steps:

```
let agentset-temp1 aircrafts with [Team != Team-of myself and distance-nowrap myself <= radius]
let list-temp1 values-from temp0 [self]
```

to convert to NetLogo 6, both lines need changes, as follows:

```
let agentset-temp1 aircrafts with [Team != [Team] of myself and distance-nowrap myself <= radius]
let list-temp1 [self] of temp0
```

I don't have your whole model to actually try this in, but I think this is right or nearly right.